# PHP file_get_contents adds white space?

Tags: php, text, whitespace, file-get-contents, space

I'm loading a text file to put inside a textarea with file_get_contents() and for some reason, white space is inserted before and after the original text each time I load it. I know the white space isn't inserted during saving, because I checked the saved file from my FTP client and there was no white space.

```
<textarea name="banner" cols="100" rows="20">
<?php echo file_get_contents('banner.txt'); ?>
</textarea>
<br/>
```

I'm using similar code for several other files, with the same result. The exact amount of white space is 16 characters long.

Comment: [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) is binary safe, it will add nothing. So the answer is no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because of the linebreaks inside the `<textarea>` tags. Write it in directly inside the tag brackets and it should be fine:

```
<textarea name="banner" cols="100" rows="20"><?= 
    file_get_contents('banner.txt'); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't see your answer.

Comment: Yes! Thank you :)